# search oracle database using php

Tags: php, oracle

Here is 4 fields one is oprid, oprname, empid and another field is email. I want to search by oprid, oprname, empid or email but it doesnt work,

> Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch

```
  <?php
   {
   include ('connection.php');
   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

  $optid = $_POST['OPRID'];
  $optdec = $_POST['OPRDEFNDESC'];
  $empid = $_POST['EMPLID'];
  $empmail = $_POST['EMAILID'];
   $query ="SELECT  * FROM OPERATOR WHERE OPRID LIKE '%".$optid."%'  
        or OPRDEFNDESC LIKE '%".$optdec."%' or EMPLID LIKE '%".$empid."%'
        or EMAILID LIKE '%".$empmail."%' "; 

        }
   else{
$query="SELECT * FROM OPERATOR";
$objParse = oci_parse ($ora_conn, $query);
   }
   ?>

<form action="multi.php" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
 <table width="500" border="0" align="center">  
<tr>  
 <th>Operator ID
   <input name="OPRID" type="text" id="OPRID" value="";>  
  <tr>  
 <th>Operator Name
 <input name="OPRDEFNDESC" type="text" id="OPRDEFNDESC" value="";>  
 <tr>  
  <th>Person ID
  <input name="EMPLID" type="text" id="EMPLID" value="";>  
   <tr>  
  <th>Email ID
   <input name="EMAILID" type="text" id="EMAILID" value="";>  
  <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>  
   </tr>  
   </table>  
  </form> 
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Operator ID</td>
    <td>Operator Name</td>
    <td>Person ID</td>
     <td>Email ID</td>
  </tr>
 <?  

 while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) 
 {  
?>  
<tr>  
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRID"];?></div></td>  
 <td><?=$objResult["OPRDEFNDESC"];?></td>  
  <td><?=$objResult["EMPLID"];?></td>  
 <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["EMAILID"];?></div></td> 
 <td align="center"><a  href="Optr_Edit.php?OprID=<?=$objResult["OPRID"];?>">Edit</a>              

</td> 
 </tr>  
 <?  
  }  
 ?>  
 </table>  
   <?  
oci_free_statement($objParse);
 oci_close($ora_conn); 
 }
 ?>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query must be executed before you can try to fetch rows. `oci_parse()` does not execute the given query.

Add the execute call before you fetch:

```
$success = oci_execute($objParse);
```

Also, in the first block of your `if`, you don't call `oci_parse()`. It's only called in the `else`. Change to call `oci_parse()` for all conditions.

Your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection because you concatenate raw POST data into it. To prevent SQL Injection, use bound parameters:

```
$optid = '%' . $_POST['OPRID'] . '%';
$optdec = '%' . $_POST['OPRDEFNDESC']. '%';
$empid = '%' . $_POST['EMPLID']. '%';
$empmail = '%' . $_POST['EMAILID']. '%';

$query ="SELECT  * FROM OPERATOR WHERE OPRID LIKE :optid  
    or OPRDEFNDESC LIKE '%:optdec%' or EMPLID LIKE :empid
    or EMAILID LIKE :empemail "; 

$objParse = oci_parse ($ora_conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':optid', $optid);
oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':optdec', $optdec);
oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':empid', $empid);
oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':empemail', $empemail);

$success = oci_execute($objParse);
```

Comment: when i am open this page data already show in the page without searching

Comment: Make sure the code is within the `if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){` block so that it only executes after searching.